# TypeScript exported class is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am exporting a class and referencing it in another file. However, I am getting this error: `demo_1.demoClass is not a constructor`. I'm not seeing any errors in the terminal, but I see the error in Chrome's console. I would expect to see a `console.log` of 1. I've looked at other answers and played around with the way I'm exporting my class, but nothing has worked.

demoClass.ts

```
export class demoClass {
name: string;

constructor(
    name: string
) {
    this.name = name;
}

init() {
    console.log(1);
}
```

}

other TS file

```
import { demoClass } from "../../src/demo/demo";

const demo: demoClass = new demoClass('foo');
demo.init();
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2019",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "ES2019"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "noEmitHelpers": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because the JavaScript file isn't being pulled down to the browser

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What are you using the bundle the generated javascript files?

Comment: I'm using webpack to bundle everything.

Comment: Is the bundled JS on the page as a script tag and if so do you see demoClass in the transpiled JS?

Comment: Yes, everything is bundled into a script embedded within the HTML page. I am seeing the class as well with this bundle